# Marketing cloud : Is it possible to find emails used in journey

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am using rest call to get journey details

```
https://{{TenantId}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/interactions?name=
```

The response is journey json which contain activities section which has all steps of journey. Step with type as EmailV2 are email step. I want to find which email is been used and get its html code

There is tag call emailid in triggeredsent section, but its a asset id and doesnt not match to email

I also used the triggeredsentdefination id and queried on triggered sent defination object, the email info i get is not correct one.

I am trying from joruney name to get to the email used and finally get its html code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem and thus wanted to share.

Suppose you have a journey with name "XXXXXXXXX", you can use the below api to get journey details :

```html
https://{{TenantId}}.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/interactions?name=XXXXXXXXXXXX&extras=all
```

This will give you a details info on the journey , a perfect JSON message . Each step in your journey = activties in the this message .

Below is copy of response message :
[image]

Activity of type = EMAILV2 is a email step from journey

The emailid which is show here , seems to id for email, but it will not give you right email from the step ,

You need to look for assets which have legacy id as emailid from above
You can do this using content api from marketing cloud

[enter link description here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/assetAdvancedQuery.html)

You need to setup query properly to get the email from journey :

```html
{
    "page": {
        "page": 1,
        "pageSize": 25
    },
    "sort": [
        {
            "property": "modifiedDate",
            "direction": "desc"
        }
    ],
    "query": {
        "orderBy": {
            "property": "modifiedDate",
            "direction": "desc"
        },
        "leftOperand": {
            "property": "data.email.legacy.legacyId",
            "simpleOperator": "equals",
            "value": 20205
        },
        "logicalOperator": "AND",
        "rightOperand": {
            "property": "assetType.id",
            "simpleOperator": "in",
            "values": [
                5,
                207,
                208,
                209
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

The emaild id from journey api maps to legacy id of assets. The response to above will get you all details and content of email.

Hope this help you.